# mysql explain filesort with index

Tags: mysql, indexing

im have query like this

```
SELECT VID, title, duration, addtime, thumb, thumbs, 
viewnumber, rate, likes, dislikes, type, hd 
FROM video WHERE active = '1' AND type = 'public' 
ORDER BY addtime DESC 
LIMIT 2052, 36;
```

when i run explain with heidisql, the result is:

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 0.999 sec. */
Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

it has the filesort inside it, does it affect performance some how? if it is, how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses a filesort when reading the rows in index order doesn't match the `ORDER BY` your query requested.

In the example query you show, you can avoid the filesort by adding this index:

```
ALTER TABLE video ADD INDEX (active, type, addtime);
```

Comment: it become : Using where, no more index and filesort

Comment: Removing the "index condition" note doesn't mean that it isn't using an index. Refer to the "key" column of the EXPLAIN. If it is not NULL, then it's naming the index that the query will use.